# Como transformar o Selenium em um executável(python)

Tags: python, selenium-webdriver, pyinstaller

Fui fazer um bot com o selenium, e na minha máquina rodou tranquilo até o executável, porém ao passar para máquina de um amigo fica dando um erro chato e não consigo resolver.

```
from selenium import webdriver
from selenium.webdriver.common.keys import Keys
import time
import random
from tkinter import *
import tkinter.messagebox
from tkinter import ttk
from _thread import *


class StoreBooks:
    def __init__(self):
        self.caughtbooks = 0
        self.pagspassed = 0

class   AMZBot():
    def __init__(self, username, password, url, code):
        self.username = username
        self.password = password
        self.url = url
        self.code = code
        self.a = 0
        firefoxProfile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile()
        firefoxProfile.set_preference("int1.accept_languages", "pt,pt-BR")
        firefoxProfile.set_preference("dom.webnotifications.enable", False)
        self.driver = webdriver.Firefox(
            firefox_profile=firefoxProfile, executable_path="\driver\geckodriver.exe"
        )

    def login(self,):
        try:

            driver = self.driver
            driver.get("https://www.amazon.com.br/ap/signin?openid.pape.max_auth_age=0&openid.return_to=https%3A%2F%2Fwww.amazon.com.br%2Fref%3Dnav_signin&openid.identity=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.assoc_handle=brflex&openid.mode=checkid_setup&openid.claimed_id=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0%2Fidentifier_select&openid.ns=http%3A%2F%2Fspecs.openid.net%2Fauth%2F2.0&")
            loginusuario = driver.find_element_by_xpath("//input[@name='email']")
            loginusuario.clear()
            loginusuario.send_keys(self.username)
            buto = driver.find_element_by_id('continue').click()
            passwd = driver.find_element_by_xpath( "//input[@name='password']")
            passwd.clear()
            passwd.send_keys(self.password)
            time.sleep(2)
            buton = driver.find_element_by_id('signInSubmit').click()
            time.sleep(2)
        except:
            time.sleep(60)
        try:
            buton = driver.find_element_by_id('continue').click()
            time.sleep(30)
        except:
            pass

        self.takebooks()

    def takebooks(self):
        driver = self.driver
        driver.get(self.url)
        time.sleep(1)
        store = StoreBooks()
        while True:
            for n in range(1,10000):

                try:
                    clicar = driver.find_element_by_id('a-autoid-'+str(n)+'-announce').send_keys(Keys.SHIFT + Keys.CONTROL + Keys.ENTER)
                    store.caughtbooks += 1
                    print("Livro Pego({})".format(store.caughtbooks))
                    time.sleep(0.5)
                    driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[-1])
                    time.sleep(1)
                    driver.close()
                    driver.switch_to_window(driver.window_handles[0])
                    time.sleep(1)
                except Exception as error:
                    #print("----")
                    pass
            try:

                nextpage = driver.find_element_by_class_name('a-last').click()
                store.pagspassed += 1
                print("Páginas passadas"+ str(store.pagspassed))
            except Exception as error:
                print(error)

            time.sleep(1)


def main():
    root = Tk()
    app = Window1(root)
    root.mainloop()
class Window1():
    def __init__(self, master):
        self.master = master
        self.master.title("BotInstagtram")
        self.master.geometry("700x500")
        self.frame = Frame(self.master)
        self.frame.pack()
        self.user = StringVar()
        self.passwd = StringVar()
        self.url = StringVar()
        self.LabelTitle = Label(self.frame, text="BOT AMAZON FREE BOOKS", font=("verdana", 30), bd=20, justify=LEFT)
        self.LabelTitle.grid(row=0, columnspan=2, pady=20, sticky=W)
        #-----------------------------------------------------------
        #Frames
        self.Loginframe1 = Frame(self.frame, width=500, height=150, bd=20, relief='ridge')
        self.Loginframe1.grid(row=1, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.Loginframe2 = Frame(self.frame, width=500, height=50, bd=10, relief='ridge')
        self.Loginframe2.grid(row=2, column=0, sticky=W)
        self.Loginframe4 = Frame(self.frame, width=500, height=50, bd=10, relief='ridge')
        self.Loginframe4.grid(row=1, column=1, sticky=W)

        ##########################################
        #Bar

        #-----------------------------------------------------------
        #Radio Button
        self.language = Label(self.Loginframe4, text="Book Language", font=('arial', 12, "bold"))
        self.language.grid()
        self.Valor= IntVar()
        self.Italian = Radiobutton(self.Loginframe4, text="Italian", value=1, variable=self.Valor, command=self.ChangingIT)
        self.Italian.grid(sticky=W)
        self.En = Radiobutton(self.Loginframe4, text="English", value=2, variable=self.Valor, command=self.ChangingEN)
        self.En.grid(sticky=W)
        self.Spanish = Radiobutton(self.Loginframe4, text="Spanish", value=3, variable=self.Valor, command=self.ChangingES)
        self.Spanish.grid(sticky=W)
        self.PT = Radiobutton(self.Loginframe4, text="Portuguese", value=4, variable=self.Valor, command=self.ChangingPT)
        self.PT.grid(sticky=W)
        self.Loginframe4.config(self.En.select())
        #-----------------------------------------------------------
        #StringVar

        self.url.set('https://www.amazon.com.br/s?i=digital-text&bbn=5475882011&rh=n%3A5308307011%2Cn%3A5308308011%2Cn%3A5475882011%2Cp_36%3A5560478011%2Cp_n_feature_browse-bin%3A6406077011&dc&language=pt_BR&_encoding=UTF8&fst=as%3Aoff&linkCode=sl2&linkId=c74a3b3b1606b3a2c5d5249ccab38e13&primeCampaignId=prime_assoc_ft&qid=1591627747&rnid=6406076011&tag=ynv-20&ref=sr_nr_p_n_feature_browse-bin_2')

        self.code = StringVar()
        #-----------------------------------------------------------
        #Frame1
        self.LabelUser = Label(self.Loginframe1, text="Name", font=('arial', 15, "bold"))
        self.LabelUser.grid()
        self.LabeltxtUser = Entry(self.Loginframe1, text="Name", font=('arial', 15, "bold"), textvariable=self.user)
        self.LabeltxtUser.grid(row=0, column=1)
        self.LabelPasswd = Label(self.Loginframe1, text="Pass", font=('arial', 15, "bold"))
        self.LabelPasswd.grid(row=1, column=0)
        self.LabeltxtPasswd = Entry(self.Loginframe1, text="Senha", font=('arial', 15, "bold"), show="*", textvariable=self.passwd)
        self.LabeltxtPasswd.grid(row=1, column=1)
        self.Botar = Label(self.Loginframe1, text="URL", font=('arial', 12, 'bold'))
        self.Botar.grid(row=2, column=0)
        self.LabeltxtURL = Entry(self.Loginframe1, text="URL", font=('arial', 15, "bold"), textvariable=self.url)
        self.LabeltxtURL.grid(row=2, column=1)
        #-----------------------------------------------------------
        #Frame2

        self.TestarConta = Button(self.Loginframe2, text="Run", width=10, font=('arial', 12, 'bold'), command=self.start)
        self.TestarConta.grid()
        #-----------------------------------------------------------
        #Frame3
        self.duvida = Button(self.Loginframe2, text="?", width=6, font=('arial', 12, 'bold'), command=self.showInfo)
        self.duvida.grid(row=0, column=1)


    def showInfo(self):
        tkinter.messagebox.showinfo("Info", "This is a bot that take every free book from Amazon, you can choose de language,\n and the URL(Based on the language you want), if you want to take every book after\n some specific page you can do it too, you just need to put the url in fild.\n Do not close the webBrowser before it took all the books or the app you crash.\n\n\nMade By Jansen Moreira")

    def ChangingIT(self):

        self.url.set("https://www.amazon.com.br/s?i=digital-text&bbn=5475882011&rh=n%3A5308307011%2Cn%3A5308308011%2Cn%3A5475882011%2Cp_36%3A5560478011%2Cp_n_feature_browse-bin%3A12636746011&dc&language=pt_BR&fst=as%3Aoff&linkCode=sl2&linkId=02095141d486184646c643456040a5b7&qid=1591752889&rnid=6406076011&ref=sr_nr_p_n_feature_browse-bin_2")

    def ChangingEN(self):
       self.url.set('https://www.amazon.com.br/s?i=digital-text&bbn=5475882011&rh=n%3A5308307011%2Cn%3A5308308011%2Cn%3A5475882011%2Cp_36%3A5560478011%2Cp_n_feature_browse-bin%3A6406077011&dc&language=pt_BR&_encoding=UTF8&fst=as%3Aoff&linkCode=sl2&linkId=c74a3b3b1606b3a2c5d5249ccab38e13&primeCampaignId=prime_assoc_ft&qid=1591627747&rnid=6406076011&tag=ynv-20&ref=sr_nr_p_n_feature_browse-bin_2')

    def ChangingES(self):
        self.url.set("https://www.amazon.com.br/s?i=digital-text&bbn=5475882011&rh=n%3A5308307011%2Cn%3A5308308011%2Cn%3A5475882011%2Cp_36%3A5560478011%2Cp_n_feature_browse-bin%3A12636744011&dc&language=pt_BR&fst=as%3Aoff&linkCode=sl2&linkId=02095141d486184646c643456040a5b7&qid=1591753012&rnid=6406076011&ref=sr_nr_p_n_feature_browse-bin_5")

    def ChangingPT(self):
        self.url.set("https://www.amazon.com.br/s?i=digital-text&bbn=5475882011&rh=n%3A5308307011%2Cn%3A5308308011%2Cn%3A5475882011%2Cp_36%3A5560478011%2Cp_n_feature_browse-bin%3A6406078011&dc&language=pt_BR&fst=as%3Aoff&linkCode=sl2&linkId=02095141d486184646c643456040a5b7&qid=1591753084&rnid=6406076011&ref=sr_nr_p_n_feature_browse-bin_5")

    def start(self):
        start_new_thread(self.Login, (1,))

    def Login(self, nada):
        nada =0
        name = (self.user.get())
        passwd = (self.passwd.get())
        url = (self.url.get())
        code = self.code
        self.jansen = AMZBot(name, passwd, url, code)
        self.jansen.login()



if __name__ == '__main__':
    main()
```

código que usei no pyinstaller

> pyinstaller -F --add-binary "C:\Users\User\PycharmProjects\AMAZON_Downloader\geckodriver.exe";"\driver" Main.py

erro

```
Unhandled exception in thread started by <bound method Window1.Login of <_main_.Window1 object at 0x000002567F86F5F8>>
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 76, in start
  File "subprocess.py", line 707, in _init_
  File "subprocess.py", line 990, in _execute_child
FileNotFoundError: [WinError 2] The system cannot find the file specified

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "Main.py", line 186, in Login
  File "Main.py", line 28, in _init_
  File "lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\firefox\webdriver.py", line 164, in _init_
  File "lib\site-packages\selenium\webdriver\common\service.py", line 83, in start
selenium.common.exceptions.WebDriverException: Message: 'geckodriver.exe' executable needs to be in PATH.
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Recomendo você utilizar a biblioteca **auto-py-to-exe**, ela permite que você gere um executável como arquivo único. Basta executar o `prompt de comando` como **administrador**, e digitar o comando `pip install auto-py-to-exe`. Para utilizá-lo, basta abrir o `cmd` (em qualquer pasta) e digitar `auto-py-exe`. Ele abrirá uma janela na qual existem diversas opções como a de gerar um .exe em um único arquivo ou em uma pasta, alterar o ícone do seu programa, escolher a pasta de destino, e a mais interessante, permitir que você esconda o console (é bom caso você esteja trabalhando com UI).

Comment: Obrigado, funcionou perfeitamente com o auto-py-to-exe. Lembrando que para mim precisou colocar **O Driver do browser na pasta que foi gerado o executável** Aqui a bibliografia dessa lib: https://pypi.org/project/auto-py-to-exe/